# Unexpected behaviour with return type of overridden method from interface using generics with extends

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter

I have the following generic interface:

```
public interface Builder<T> {
    public T getObject();
}
```

The class `EntityBuilder` implements this interface:

```
public class EntityBuilder<E extends Entity> implements Builder<E> {
    ...
    @Override
    public E getObject() {
        return new Entity(ID, creationTime, lastChangeTime);
    }
    ...
}
```

Where `Entity` is a simple DTO:

```
public class Entity {
    ...
    public Entity(long ID, Date creationTime, Date lastChangeTime) {
        ID = ID;
        this.creationTime = creationTime;
        this.lastChangeTime = lastChangeTime;
    }
    ...
```

The problem I have is that in `public E getObject()` I `"cannot convert from Entity to E"`, however, declaring `<E extends Entity>` asserts that E is an Entity (or subclass), which Entity apparently is.

What am I missing?

Sidenote: I could of course simplify this to `EntityBuilder implements Builder<Entity>`, but then I couldn't extend EntityBuilder in something like `PersonBuilder extends EntityBuilder<Person> (implements Builder<Person>)`, ie. I would be missing the assertion that `PersonBuilder` implements `Builder<Person>`. Maybe there's a more elegant solution to this which also solves the problem described above.

Comment: What would `new EntityBuilder<MyEntity>().getObject()` return if `MyEntity` is a subclass of `Entity`?

Comment: Still an Entity, which is not a subclass of MyEntity, which violates basic principles of OOP in Java - because I then would've declared the method returns a MyEntity which an Entity is not - which is bad :(. Thx!

Comment: `public abstract class EntityBuilder<E extends Entity>` and `public abstract E getObject();` would be a quick fix that comes to my mind (and indeed I don't need to instantiate EntityBuilder), but this doesn't fully satisfy me.

Comment: *I don't need to instantiate EntityBuilder and it would be conceptually sound I believe
*but this doesn't fully satisfy me and would require slightly redundant code

Comment: As far as I understand `PersonBuilder` should implements `Builder<Entity>` and `Builder<Person>` at same time. It is not possible directly, but we can look forward to good workaround.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are getting that error because you're returning an `Entity`. You're saying that E should an Entity, but that doesn't necessarily mean that the Entity you're returning is an E (kind of like a square is a rectangle but a rectangle isn't necessarily a square). I believe you can fix it by type casting your return as `return (E) new Entity(ID, creationTime, lastChangeTime);`

Comment: Thx for your response. That would solve the compiler error, yes. But this is not one of those few cases where I would use a type-cast, but rather one where I know I made some kind of nonsense because I've been up too long programming ^^.

Comment: This would be unsafe and would throw an exception the minute you try to assign it to a variable of the real type of E outside the class if E is not Entity.